# red5 - Where are the application log files kept?

Tags: java, red5

I just wanted to ask where the application logs are kept, so if i had code in my class as so:

import org.red5.logging.Red5LoggerFactory;

logger.debug("Recording show for: {}", conn.getScope().getContextPath());

whwre would this text be written to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you set the `logger` variable? Also, found some version of the code online http://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/java/server/trunk/src/org/red5/logging/Red5LoggerFactory.java?r=3563

Comment: @NickODell- you set the logger variable as so: private static final Logger logger = Red5LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class, "recorder");

Comment: We use slf4j and Logback by default. Log file locations are based on the logger configuration file depending on which appender you use. In most cases the red5/log directory is where you want to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[They're using the](http://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/java/server/trunk/src/org/red5/logging/Red5LoggerFactory.java?r=3563) `org.slf4j.Logger` class, it seems.

From [this](http://runjva.appspot.com/logging101/index.html) site, I think that it should be logging to standard out or standard error. However, I read the API, and it looks like there is a variable to control logging level. Are you getting any debug-level messages?

Comment: thanks for replying. I am not sure, i am new to RED5. What i am trying to do is create a client application in flash and broadcast audio to all the clients connected to the server. Now i believe this is achieved using shared objects is this true?, i have just started looking through some samples and i am now trying to test my current application, but in order to do this i don't have a trace of what my code is doing at the moment on the server side. That is why i was asking i need a log file to just see what my code is currently doing when executed.